# Connect Ubuntu server 18.04 to Wi-Fi without installing additional tools over apt-get

Tags: networking, apt, server, 18.04, offline

I just need to know if there is any way of connecting Ubuntu server v.18.04 over my wifi network adapter without installing any additional packages. I've been into many online tutorials and all of them start with how we use "apt-get" over the terminal and amend the configuration over a tool.
I am new to this so sorry for the basic question, but I couldn't find anything similar as topic. The problem is my machine doesn't have access to the internet and it seems weird I can't just connect it. There is no Gnome installed, so I couldn't just click the connect to the internet button. Is there any way to set this up while offline and without a tool? Please advise.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and also: `iwconfig` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Says that "iwconfig" is not found. As I said, I have no connection so I couldn't install it over the apt-get. This is my point. Also at /etc/netplan there is only one file called 50-cloud-init.yami and these are the lines active: network: ethernets: {} version: 2

The wireless adapter is called wlp3s0. 
I tried with editing: /etc/network/interfaces and restarted wlp3s0 over ifconfig, but it just doesn't work. 
I hope if you could provide me with any other suggestions. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that yours is a server that is *not* intended to be a cloud instance. If this is correct, let’s follow the recommendation included in the 50-cloud-init.yaml file. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "network: {config: disabled}"  >  /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg
exit
```

Next, let’s remove the file and simultaneously back it up:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml  ~/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

Next, verify the wireless interface name with the command:

```
ifconfig
```

Substitute the interface you found below if not wlp3s0.

Now let’s write a new file using the command line text editor *nano*:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Write the following:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.21/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,192.168.0.1]
      access-points: 
        "******":
          password: "**********"
```

Of course, substitute your exact details here. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and Exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor. Save your netplan changes changes by running the commands:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Please note and follow the spacing and indentation. Also note that the SSID and password are in between quotes ".

Reboot and test:

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your detailed response! Working fine for me now. Many thanks!

Comment: Awesome! If my answer has been helpful, please accept it. The searchers will appreciate it. https://askubuntu.com/tour